# I need to create a .sh installer file

Tags: scripts

I need to create a .sh installer file. I have the files, i just need to know the commands that will lead the terminal into placing the files in certain locations. there is a folder that needs to be placed in the `/var` directory, and a file in the `/etc/init.d` directory. Does anyone know what commands in the file are appropriate?

there is a folder that needs to be placed in the `/var` directory, and a file in the `/etc/init.d` directory.

Comment: it would help us a lot if you could tell us which files you wanna install and where to put them

Comment: sorry, there is a folder that needs to be placed in the /var directory, and a file in the /etc/init.d directory.

Comment: By "installer file", do you mean executing an installer program, or moving files around on the hard drive?

Comment: You mean sh file installers like installer of netbeans IDE?

Comment: executing an installer program with the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, a shell `.sh` script is nothing more than the same commands you would type at the command line.  For instance, if your files are "a.sh, b.txt, c.conf" and they need to reside in `/var`, and "d.sh" goes in "/etc/init.d", then you would do something like this:

```
cp a.sh /var
cp b.txt /var
cp c.conf /var
cp d.sh /etc/init.d
```

That assumes the installer file is separate from the other files.  If you need to make a *single* unified installer script that *contains* these file, then you'll want to look a ["shar" file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) (short for "Shell Archive").

A shar file can also setup permissions and take other actions that might be necessary for your installation.  You can use the `chown` and `chmod` command as necessary in the install script you write, too.

Comment: do you know the command that is able to stop, pause, or ask for choise(yes/no)?

Comment: You will use the `read` command.  Googling for "shell script input" pulls up a number of example sites, this page has a good example: http://www.thelinuxblog.com/shell-script-get-user-input/